# UIPopoverPresentationController can't setup arrow color

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to present popover with UIPopoverPresentationController class on the iPhone.
I need to present navigation controller inside the popover. So I do the following:

```
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    viewController.preferredContentSize = size;
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    self.currentPopoverController = navigationController.popoverPresentationController;
    self.currentPopoverController.backgroundColor = [UIColor commonApplicationBgColor];//My common app blue color
    self.view.alpha = 0.7;
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It is working, but arrow colour is differ from the popover navigation bar background colour. I checked they use the same [UIColor commonApplicationBgColor], but it looks like arrow colour is darker. Tried setup alpha for self.currentPopoverController.backgroundColor, but it is still has wrong color. 
Please check image:
[image]

Comment: Are you presenting it from rect ?

Comment: Yes, here is the code:
self.currentPopoverController.delegate = self;
self.currentPopoverController.sourceView = self.view;
self.currentPopoverController.sourceRect = frame;

Comment: Popover don't work very good since iOS 7. Apple is not using that very much in their own applications and this is the result.

Answer (score -1):

if you don't want arrow then you can pass 0 to `permittedarrowdirection` like,

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:YOUR_RECT
                                inView:self.view 
              permittedArrowDirections:0
                              animated:YES];
```

Update :

you can set like,

```
 popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController];
 popover.backgroundColor = contentViewController.view.backgroundColor;
```

set bacground color to popovercontroller.

Update 2 :

```
myPopoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
[self presentViewController:myPopoverViewController animated: YES completion: nil];

// Get the popover presentation controller and configure it.
UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController =
     [myPopoverViewController popoverPresentationController];
 presentationController.permittedArrowDirections =
     UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft | UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight;
  presentationController.sourceView = myView;
 presentationController.sourceRect = sourceRect;

presentationController.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; //set your expacted color here.
```

Hope this will help

Comment: No, I need arrow. The problem is in popover arrow background color. The color is darker than popover navigation bar color. Please check image.

Comment: Is it iPad version? Check please my code, I am using popoverPresentationController

Comment: Sorry, first i have understand iPad's popoverController. I have updated my answer check it.

Comment: Thanks, But my code is the same:
self.currentPopoverController.backgroundColor = [UIColor commonApplicationBgColor];//My common app blue color
and it doesn't work, the result is on the image screen above.